# Perl - Regex in CSV

Tags: regex, perl, csv, delimiter, substitution

following problem:

I have a delimited file which rows have 25 or 26 fields.
For all rows having 25 fields I need to add an empty row after the 13th field, so that it will have 26 fields as well.

Old:

```
Z|432651242|987654321|XYZ|Abc|DEFEF||Abc-De-Fg|18|33221|Qwerty|18.06.3213|abc||123|Tepp|11.07.4443|2|||||4433322342344||
```

New:

```
Z|432651242|987654321|XYZ|Abc|DEFEF||Abc-De-Fg|18|33221|Qwerty|18.06.3213|abc|||123|Tepp|11.07.4443|2|||||4433322342344||
```

I managed to filter the lines that need to be changed:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my (@cols,$fieldLength,);
while(<>){
  @cols = split('\|', $_);
  $fieldLength=@cols;
  if ($fieldLength==25){
  print $_;
  }
}
```

My idea was to substitute the delimiter "|" on the 13th occurrence with "||", but couldn't manage to do so. I tried to google it up but the examples didn't work for me.

Could anybody help me with that please?

I would also appreciate a solution using an CSV module from CPAN.

Comment: `Text::CSV` will be safer than regex...

Comment: `Text::CSV` is the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can safely assume that the delimiter `|` never appears in the data of a field, then you can use `split` and `splice`, but [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV) is safer.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>)
{
    my @cols = split /[|]/;
    if (scalar(@cols) == 25)
    {
        splice(@cols, 13, 0, '');
        $_ = join('|', @cols);
    }
    print;
}
```

This seems to produce your desired output.  Given input file:

```
Z|432651242|987654321|XYZ|Abc|DEFEF||Abc-De-Fg|18|33221|Qwerty|18.06.3213|abc||123|Tepp|11.07.4443|2|||||4433322342344||
Z|432651242|987654321|XYZ|Abc|DEFEF||Abc-De-Fg|18|33221|Qwerty|18.06.3213|abc|def|123|Tepp|11.07.4443|2|||||4433322342344||
```

(where the second line has `def` in place of an empty field so you can see exactly where the insertion occurs), the output is:

```
Z|432651242|987654321|XYZ|Abc|DEFEF||Abc-De-Fg|18|33221|Qwerty|18.06.3213|abc|||123|Tepp|11.07.4443|2|||||4433322342344||
Z|432651242|987654321|XYZ|Abc|DEFEF||Abc-De-Fg|18|33221|Qwerty|18.06.3213|abc||def|123|Tepp|11.07.4443|2|||||4433322342344||
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Do you maybe know, how would the Text::CSV would look like?

Comment: It would look more or less like the code that [TLP](http://stackoverflow.com/users/725418/tlp) showed in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067595/perl-regex-in-csv/18067728#18067728).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) to parse the lines, insert an empty line with splice, and print it out. Something like this should work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    sep_char => '|',
    eol      => $/,
});

while (my $row = $csv->getline(*ARGV)) {
    splice(@$row, 12, 0, '') if @$row == 25;
    $csv->print(*STDOUT, $row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just for curiousity because I was trying around but it didn't work. How would be the regex solution?

Comment: It would be needlessly complicated.

Comment: Seems so, but I first couldn't believe that it could be so complicated just to replace the nth occurrence of something here. I'm asking because I can not use modules where I need to use it.

Comment: @TLP: the snippet has too many bugs: construction does not work (options have to be in a hashref, it seems), there's no check `or die Text::CSV->error_diag ();`, the script does not compile: `$r` should probably be `$row`.

Comment: I changed $r to $row but still get an error: Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at .\correct.pl line 11. That's the getline-function

Comment: @SlavenRezic Fair enough, I just transcribed it from a one-liner, so I missed some things, fixed now. I doubt there's any *real* need to check if we successfully created a csv object with a `die` statement.

Comment: @user2557981 I made some mistakes when typing in the code. It should work now though.